# Minimax Algorithm, Machine Learning or Deep Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

From my understanding, artificial intelligence can be divided into two subsets, deep learning and machine learning. Which one of those categories does the minimax algorithm fall into when developing an AI to play chess?

Comment: 1. Arguably off-topic/too vague for Stackoverflow. 2. This is fundamentally misinformed. Deep learning is a _subset_ of machine learning. "Artificial intelligence" encompasses much more than just machine learning. The minimax algorithm is _not_ a machine learning technique.

Comment: Where would the minimax algorithm lie within the artificial intelligence sector. @xdurch0

Answer (score 1):

1- AI is much wider than Machine Learning. ML is a subset of Learning, Learning is a subset of AI

2- Deep Learning is a platform for ML( if not a subset of ML), to help do the automatic feature selection at the same time as training.

3- There is not really such a boundary of which algorithm belongs to which part of AI

4- A major part of AI named "Problem Solving" in the [AI modern approach book](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/). MinMax has been discussed there if I am not mistaken